# Php. If empty statement,

Tags: php, html, web, notepad++

In my guestbook, I have made a "button" to view the guestbook, Since it takes you to another page. The problem is i have this code
`if (empty($name) || (empty($comment)))

       {

      echo "Error";

      exit;

      }`
So it will come up with that error.No matter how i link to the guestbook. It should only say Error if you click on the "submit button" and if you have left out your name and comment.

The whole code: Before, i changed the variables to english for better understanding , but i just keep it in danish now.

?>

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Fælles Forum</title>
</head>
<body>                        
<form action="skriv.php" method="POST">
<br>
 Navn <input type="text" name="fornavn" />
<br>
<br>
E_mail <input type="text" name="email" />
<br>
<br>
<p>Besked<p> <textarea rows="7" name="kommentar" cols="40"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
Adresse <input type="text" "Adreese" name="adresse" />
<br>
<br>
Mobil nr <input type="text" name="mobil" size="12" maxlength="8" 
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Save" name = "save"  />
<input type="reset" value="Reset"  />
</form>
<form action="skriv.php" method="GET">
<input type="submit" value="Read all messages" name = "read">
</form>
<FORM METHOD="GET" ACTION="Login.php"> <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Logout"> </FORM> 
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
<input type="submit" value="Delete all messages" name = "delete">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
$handle = fopen("TXTfil.txt", "w");
fclose($handle);
echo "Alle kommentare slettet!";
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

It does not allow me to post the other page of code.. So i have taken a picture of the second page.

http://i46.tinypic.com/2e3ac7r.png

Comment: Without more code it is difficult to give an accurate, correct answer. How are you instantiating `$name` and `$comment`? If these are the field names from your form, then you need `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['comment']`. But this is just a guess without more code.

Comment: taken a picture of the second page, so you can see it now:)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly; you want a dual-purpose page.  It should display the guestbook, but if the user clicked the submit button, it should also add a comment.  If you click the submit button and leave 'name' or 'comment' blank, you want it to error out.

You can check if the user came to your page using the submit button by checking the value of its name.

Be sure to assign a name to your button:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="AddComment" value="Save" />
```

and in your target page:

```
if ($_POST['AddComment']=='Save') {
  if (empty($name) || (empty($comment))) {
    echo "Error";
    exit;
  }
  // save logic goes here
}
else {
  // show guestbook
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. But if i click the "save" button now, it  shows the page with no error . only the "read all messages" that should do that